# Getting a user input after an Embed (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So im trying to make a sort of pokemon catching bot just for fun and to test my skill, I've invited my friend to help me. We're trying to make a random spawn and a catching mechanism. The catching mechaninism didn't really work well since it detect the user input before the embed not after the embed which is impossible to catch. Any help will be much appreciate.

```
 bot.on("message", async message => {
    const args = message.content
    .slice(prefix.length)
    .trim()
    .split(/ +/g);
  let r = message.content.slice(bot.prefix.length+6)
  let dex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 921) + 1);
  let random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
    if(random===5){
       const options = {
        url: `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${dex}`,
        json: true
      }
       get(options).then(body => {
      let Embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("A Wild pokemon has appeared")
      .setDescription(`Quick, catch that pokemon!`)  
      .setThumbnail(body.sprites.front_default)
      .setFooter(body.name)
      .setColor("#00eaff")
      message.channel.send(Embed);
    })
      get(options).then(body => {
        if(message.content==(body.name)){
         message.reply("You just caught a " + body.name);
         }
         else {
           message.reply("Not that one!");
         }
      })
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not impossible to catch. You can easily achieve this by using [`awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages)

```js
bot.on("message", async message => {
  const args = message.content
    .slice(prefix.length)
    .trim()
    .split(/ +/g);
  let r = message.content.slice(bot.prefix.length + 6)
  let dex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 921) + 1);
  let random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
    if (random === 5) {
      const options = {
        url: `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${dex}`,
        json: true
      }
      get(options).then(async body => {
        let Embed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle("A Wild pokemon has appeared")
          .setDescription(`Quick, catch that pokemon!`)
          .setThumbnail(body.sprites.front_default)
          .setFooter(body.name)
          .setColor("#00eaff")
        const msg = await message.channel.send(Embed);
        const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
        msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] }) // 1 minute timer & max of 1 attempt at answering
          .then(collected => {
            get(options).then(body => {
              if (collected.first().content == (body.name)) {
                message.reply("You just caught a " + body.name);
              }
              else {
                message.reply("Not that one!");
              }
            })
          })
          .catch(() => message.reply('you did not guess in time!'));
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: It show me an error, "await is only valid in async function"

Comment: Edited the answer, you just need to add async to the function block

Comment: It fixes my problem but now everytime I guessed it correct it shows the incorrect message

Comment: can you tell me the output of `console.log(body.name)` and `console.log(collected.content)`?

Comment: body.name : hawlucha,
collected : isn't the same at all

Comment: it isn't the same

Comment: it shows me a random output, Its too long I can't put it in the comments

Comment: That was my fault, I forgot that `collected` returns a collection, I fixed my answer

Comment: 1 question tho, how do I make it so theres no max attempt?

Comment: I've tried removing the max : 1, but it didn't work

Comment: If you want to collect multiple guesses without a number limit use `createMessageCollector()` instead of `awaitMessages()`: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createMessageCollector